# How to trigger App Center Push from my asp.net Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android, android-push-notification, visual-studio-app-center-push

I'm making an android `Xamarin.Android`. I finished the android application and now I want to add remote push notifications based on my item condition in my database that can accessed from `ASP.Net Web Api`.

I succeeded sent notifications from App Center Push to my application. I already authorized the App Center Client and now can access the app center api. I'm planning to merge the app center api to my `asp.net web api` if possible. But I don't know where to start it.

Should I put the app center action to my controller (I don't know if its working or not) or there's another way?
here's my controller:
    public class InventoriesController : ApiController
    {
        private InventoryRepository _inventoryRepository;

```
    public InventoriesController()
    {
        _inventoryRepository = new InventoryRepository();
    }

    // GET: api/Categories
    public IHttpActionResult GetInventories()
    {
        IEnumerable<InventoryViewModel> inv = _inventoryRepository.GetAll().ToList().Select(e=> new InventoryViewModel(e)).ToList();
        return Ok(inv);
    }

    // GET: api/Categories/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(InventoryViewModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetInventory(Guid id)
    {
        InventoryViewModel inventory = new InventoryViewModel (_inventoryRepository.GetSingle(e => e.Id == id));
        if (inventory == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(inventory);
    }

    // PUT: api/Categories/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutInventory(Guid id, InventoryViewModel inventory)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != inventory.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        try
        {
            _inventoryRepository.Edit(inventory.ToModel());

        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!InventoryExist(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Categories
    [ResponseType(typeof(InventoryViewModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostInventory(InventoryViewModel inventory)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            _inventoryRepository.Add(inventory.ToModel());
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (InventoryExist(inventory.Id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = inventory.Id }, inventory);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Categories/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Inventory))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteInventory(Guid id)
    {
        Inventory inventory = _inventoryRepository.GetSingle(e => e.Id == id);
        if (inventory == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        await _inventoryRepository.DeleteAsync(inventory);


        return Ok(inventory);
    }
   private bool InventoryExist(Guid id)
    {
        IQueryable<Inventory> inv = _inventoryRepository.GetAll();
        return inv.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
```

And this is my model:

```
    public class InventoryViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public bool IsConsumed { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
        public Guid StorageId { get; set; }
        public string AddedUserId { get; set; }

        public Inventory ToModel()
        {
            return new Inventory
            {
                Id = (Id == Guid.Empty) ? Guid.NewGuid() : Id,
                ExpirationDate = ExpirationDate,
                Price = Price,
                ProductId=ProductId,
                StorageId=StorageId,
                ItemName=ItemName,
                IsDeleted=IsDeleted,
                IsConsumed=IsConsumed,
                AddedUserId = AddedUserId,
            };
        }
        public InventoryViewModel()
        {

        }

        public InventoryViewModel(Inventory i)
        {
            this.Id = i.Id;
            this.ExpirationDate = i.ExpirationDate;
            this.Price = i.Price;
            this.ProductId = i.ProductId;
            this.StorageId = i.StorageId;
            this.ItemName = i.ItemName;
            this.AddedUserId = i.AddedUserId;
        }
    }
```

I want to make the app center send notification based on Expired Date on my `Inventories model` and `AddedUserId`. So its my web self made `web api` who send the notification to my apps.
I read this documentation: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/pushapi][1] but still don't know where I have to write in my `Web Api`.

Hope someone here can help me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/pushapi)?

Comment: I have.. but still no clue where I have to start in my web api.

Comment: You can reach out to App Center support by logging into https://appcenter.ms/sign-in?original_url=%2Fapps and clicking the chat icon in the lower right corner of the screen. You could get a better support there. :)

Comment: Here's a screenshot if you're having trouble finding the chat [icon](https://www.screencast.com/t/uF8S5o0o0)

Answer (score 1):

You can find detail here in appcenter REST API documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/rest-api

Appcenter REST API swagger: https://openapi.appcenter.ms/